# How to derive equation for probability current density in relativistic quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

How does one derive equation for probability current density in relativistic quantum mechanics? I am asking for textbook-styled explicit derivation. No need for any other background knowledge.

Comment: Are you asking for the explicit derivation (something found in a textbook), or are you asking where one begins? Or, less likely, are you asking literally how to do it? The answer to which would be "first you learn some basic to advanced level mathematics, then you learn relativity and quantum mechanics separately...."

Comment: I am asking for explicit derivation. Somehow I can't find it.

Comment: Here's a useful article: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00670509

Comment: typed "probability current density relativistic quantum mechanics" into google. This was fourth hit

Comment: Section 3.1.4 in [this online PDF](http://www.quantumfieldtheory.info/website_Chap03.pdf) derives the spin-zero probability current in relativistic QM (not QFT). Then, in 3.7.1, the author explains how the result in QFT can be derived in the same way.